# Error: Fragment already added: GrowthStoryFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am getting the following error:  **Fragment already added: GrowthStoryFragment** when i do swipe from GrowthStory to ShareStory fragment inside tablayout using viewpager.
Here's the FragmentStatePagerAdapter code:

```
class ViewDetailsFragmentAdapter(val supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager, internal var totalTabs: Int) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager) {
    private val pages: SparseArray<Fragment> by lazy(::SparseArray)

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        return when (position) {
            0 ->  existing<GrowthStoryFragment>() ?: GrowthStoryFragment()
            1 -> existing<ShareStoryFragment>() ?: ShareStoryFragment()
            2 -> existing<PurchaseDynamicsFragment>() ?: PurchaseDynamicsFragment()
            3 -> existing<BrandHealthFragment>() ?: BrandHealthFragment()
            else -> return null
        }
    }

    private inline fun <reified Fragment> existing(): android.support.v4.app.Fragment? =
            supportFragmentManager.getFragments().firstOrNull { it is android.support.v4.app.Fragment }
    // this counts total number of tabs
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return totalTabs
    }

}
```

and this is the Activity hosting these fragments:

```
class ViewDetailsActivity : BaseActivity(), FilterOptionsDialogFragment.onApplyEventListener, BusinessUnitDialogFragment.afterDoneClick {


    private lateinit var pagerAdapter: ViewDetailsFragmentAdapter
    private var myFragmentFlag = 0

    private var TAG = "ViewDetailsActivity"

    override fun getContentView(): Int = R.layout.activity_view_details

    override fun onViewReady(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, intent: Intent?) {


        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("Growth Story"))
        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("Share Story"))
        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("Purchase Dynamics"))
        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("Brand Health Track"))
        tabLayout.tabMode = TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE
        tabLayout.tabGravity = Gravity.CENTER
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#a1a1a1"), Color.parseColor("#ff8a00"))

        pagerAdapter = ViewDetailsFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager, tabLayout!!.tabCount)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        viewPager.isFocusableInTouchMode = true

        scrollListener()

        viewPager!!.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))

        tabLayout!!.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                viewPager!!.currentItem = tab.position
                when (tab.position) {
                    0 -> {
//                        myFragmentFlag = 0
                        left_scroll.visibility = View.GONE
                        right_scroll.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    1 -> {
//                        myFragmentFlag = 1
                        right_scroll.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    2 -> {
//                        myFragmentFlag = 2
                        left_scroll.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        right_scroll.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    3 -> {
//                        myFragmentFlag = 3
                        left_scroll.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        right_scroll.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

            }
        })

        tvTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._16ssp))
        tvTitle.setText("Category Deep Dive")
        ivBack.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            finish()
        })
        ivLogo.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val addFrag = FilterOptionsDialogFragment.newInstance()
            addFrag.show(supportFragmentManager, "add")
        })

        vd_edit_icon.setOnClickListener({
            val buFrag = BusinessUnitDialogFragment.newInstance()
            buFrag.show(supportFragmentManager, "add")
        })

        vd_edit_icon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    fun scrollListener() {
        left_scroll.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val itemnum = viewPager.currentItem
            viewPager.currentItem = itemnum - 1
        })

        right_scroll.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val itemnum = viewPager.currentItem
            viewPager.currentItem = itemnum + 1
        })
    }

    override fun someEvent(countryId: String?, dateRange: String?, specs: String?) {
        val getFragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(viewPager.currentItem)
        Log.e(TAG,"Fragment names: "+ supportFragmentManager.fragments.toString())

        if(getFragment is GrowthStoryFragment){
            getFragment.myfilterOptions(countryId, dateRange, specs)
        }else if(getFragment is ShareStoryFragment){
            getFragment.myfilterOptions(countryId, dateRange, specs)
        }else if(getFragment is PurchaseDynamicsFragment){
            getFragment.myfilterOptions(countryId, dateRange, specs)
        }else if(getFragment is BrandHealthFragment){
            getFragment.myfilterOptions(countryId, dateRange, specs)
        }
    }

    override fun onDoneClicked(item: String) {

        val getFragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(viewPager.currentItem)

        if(getFragment is GrowthStoryFragment){
            getFragment.getBuName(item)
        }else if(getFragment is ShareStoryFragment){
            getFragment.getBuName(item)
        }else if(getFragment is PurchaseDynamicsFragment){
            getFragment.getBuName(item)
        }else if(getFragment is BrandHealthFragment){
            getFragment.getBuName(item)
        }

    }

}
```

Please tell what I am doing wrong here? I have to keep the reference of these fragments same, i can't use new Fragment()

**Update**:
Full Stacktrace of the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: GrowthStoryFragment{cca46b5 #0 id=0x7f0901bc}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1916)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:765)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:168)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:273)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Can you post full exception with line numbers?

Comment: @Kushal done please check.